# How make localization for toasts?

Tags: android, localization, toast

I'm wrote localization for ui texts using

```
String languageToLoad  = "en_EN";
 Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad); 
 Locale.setDefault(locale);
 Configuration config = new Configuration();
 config.locale = locale;
 context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config,context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

This good working for UI views, but my toasts don't have this. How fix it?
Strings was created in strings.xml with Locale qualifier.

Comment: are you pass a string resource to your toast? 

is the toast language showing different from the current app language?

Comment: Yes, it is. I'm make choise another language and it don't changed. I'm wrote custom class for changing lang in app, indepent from device locale/

Comment: make sure you have a translation to the text that your'e passed to the toast in same language that app using it, and try to pass string with getString() function in toast.

Comment: That's work that! Thanks, @AmrJyniat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite easy:

```
String string = getString(R.string.your_string_name);
```

If the string is saved in the right language folder it will be localised automatically.

Read more here: [https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#:~:text=android%3Atext%3D%22%40string%2Fhello%22%20%2F%3E&text=String%20string%20%3D%20getString%20(R.,int)%20to%20retrieve%20a%20string](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#:%7E:text=android%3Atext%3D%22%40string%2Fhello%22%20%2F%3E&text=String%20string%20%3D%20getString%20(R.,int)%20to%20retrieve%20a%20string).